# Routing my mail server through Google spam filters

Tags: webapp-rec, spam-prevention

I've been told in the past that Google had a free spam filter service. The service would allow me to point my MX records to Google, then they would forward all cleaned mail to my server.

Is this service still available for free?

I've seen their Postini service, but this isn't the service I was told about before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Forward your email to gmail, or point the MX domain to google apps, get it cleaned, and set up a filter to send it to any email address.

Comment: Hi tobylane,Thanks for the response. I don't want to use Gmail for email client, so the MX point to Google Apps is probably the best option. Can you provide a URL to the service you are specifically referring to? Is this a free service or low cost service? I notice they price by the "user", I assume that isn't per email account -- am I wrong?